# How to use custom HTML and Styling in AngularDart Material Expansion Panel heading?

Tags: html, angular-dart

Is it possible to use custom HTML and Styling in a AngularDart Material Expansion Panel heading?

I would ideally like to add a material-chip next to a title. For example next to 'Ordinary Panel' in the image below.

[image: Ordinary Panel]

Reading [this](https://angulardart.github.io/angular_components/?utm_source=dart-lang_github_io&utm_medium=Redirect&utm_content=meta_refresh&utm_campaign=gh-pages#/material_expansion_panel) documentation I can add text to the header through the name input. And I can edit this styling through some css like:

```
:host ::ng-deep header .primary-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

But how would I do something like putting a button or material-chip alongside a title in the header?

What I've tried:

You can add custom buttons to the expansion panel through adding a div with an action tag like so:

```
<div action>
    <material-button (trigger)="functionCall()">
        Button Text
    </material-button>
</div>
```

This is also shown in the source code of the documentation of this example:
[image: Expansion panel example]

The DOM shows the action buttons present with this class:

[image: Action buttons presenting in the DOM]

And the header presents with this class.

[image: Header presenting in the DOM]

Creating a div with a 'header' tag has no effect (unsurprisingly) as it's not in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Expand icon needs to be disabled, to show custom actions.

> alwaysHideExpandIcon bool*
> If true, the expand icon should never be visible.

```
<material-expansionpanel
  [alwaysHideExpandIcon]="true"
  [hideExpandedHeader]="true"
  name="Panel with header actions on the right">
  <div action class="action">
    <material-button>
      Edit
    </material-button>
    <material-button>
      Duplicate
    </material-button>
  </div>
  This is a panel with additional actions on the right part of the header.
  Clicking header actions doesn't expand the panel.
</material-expansionpanel>
```

Here is the source code of [Material Expansion Panel](https://github.com/angulardart/angular_components/blob/1f7d1a0d16fc76417c84cc8ecf747eb6024644fe/angular_components/lib/material_expansionpanel/material_expansionpanel.html#L54)

There are few other ng-contents with tags "name" and "value" that you can use. They don't require disabling the expand icon.

> One or more panels are grouped together in a expansion-panel-set. When a panel is clicked on, the panel contents expand. A panel consists of a name, a value, optional secondary text, and the expanded panel contents.
> Content element with attribute value will be used as the "value" of the panel contents when it is in a collapsed state
> Interactions with a panel are done through the parent expansion-set. The set takes into account the state of the other panels in the set, and issues the appropriate actions onto each individual panel.